# Command 'chrontab' not found No manual entry for chrontab (pip install?)

Tags: bash, python, cron, 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04

My chron service is running.

```
Jul 23 08:01:31 blah CRON[65443]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 23 08:01:31 blah CRON[65443]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 23 08:17:01 blah CRON[65715]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jul 23 08:17:01 blah CRON[65716]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 23 08:17:01 blah CRON[65715]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 23 09:17:01 blah CRON[66488]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jul 23 09:17:01 blah CRON[66488]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 23 10:17:01 blah CRON[67282]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jul 23 10:17:01 blah CRON[67282]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

I suspect a python script I installed modified the path and hosed it.

Checked my path and... (formatted for readability)

```
/home/blah/.local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
/home/blah/bin
/usr/java/openjdk/jdk-16.0.1/bin
```

Checked my default path and I see nothing missing...

```
blah@whatever:/etc$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

/etc/chrontab file does not exist even as root.

I get this message as root and my regular user account.  I did install pip and pip install erome which is a web scraping program.  Python script appears to work... though its out of date.

The pip install, needed hundreds of megs :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo, or a missspelling. It's not `chron`, but `cron`. So the command is `crontab`, the file you're looking for is `/etc/crontab` and so forth ;)

Comment: Thank you for revealing my genius.